# How do I upload a file to a subfolder even if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a Django app that needs to create a file in google drive: in FolderB/Sub1/Sub2/file.pdf. I have the id for FolderB but I don't know if Sub1 or Sub2 even exist. If not it should be created and the file.pdf should be put in it.

I figure I can look at children at each level and create the folder at each level if its not there, but this seems like a lot of checks and api calls just to create one file. Its also a harder task trying to accommodate multiple folder structures (ie, one python function that can accept any path of any depth and upload a file there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you have presented is the correct one. As you have realized, the Drive file system is not exactly like a hierarchical file system, so you will have to perform these checks.

One optimization you could perform is to try to find the grand-child folder (Sub2) first, so you will save a number of calls.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. How do i find/create a grandchild directly? My understanding of files.search is that I can look for the title "Sub2" but I have to cycle through the results to find one with the parent "Sub1" (which requires I know the id of "Sub1")?